# How to detect a new firebase user created in cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to detect, when a new user is created in firebase auth, then react to it. I need to do this in javascript, for a cloud function. It must be for real-time database.

Here is how one does it in firestore:

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
//    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({ email: user.email });
//    const intent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({
//      customer: customer.id,
//    });
//    await admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({
//      customer_id: customer.id,
//      setup_secret: intent.client_secret,
//    });
//    return;
//  });
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
 exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.database
 .ref('/PeopleWhoFollowMe/{uid}/{followerUID}')
 .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
   const uid = context.params.uid
   const followerUID = context.params.followerUID
   //addNewFollowToNotif(uid, followerUID)
   return updateUsersTimeLines(uid, followerUID) 
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has AdditionalUserInfo isNewUser

`AdditionalUserInfo: { isNewUser: boolean; profile: Object | null; providerId: string; username?: string | null }`

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
  console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser);
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#additionaluserinfo

---

```
exports.onCreateAuthUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
   console.log(user);
  //do other stuff
});
```

Its hard to know exactly what you are doing but this will check when user is created it will find that path on db and add that data. What you need is `user` object that has UserData

Comment: I implemented this like this (https://ibb.co/vL86q17) and get the following error: Each then() should return a value or throweslintpromise/always-return, so I resolve it via quick fix: // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return. Is this OK? Or does it change the functionaliity?

Comment: thats Editor error, eslint. Check if it work . It should be fine

Comment: It wont deploy, the way I have it. Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Comment: Yes because you are doing wrong, let me check if I can make it work, That firestore is fine

Comment: I implemented your code, run deploy but get:  Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './internalFunctions'

Comment: thats probably functions.database or updateUsersTimeLines is throwing that. You should not copy paste because mine is pseudo code.

Comment: I removed all those things, and attempted to deploy with nothing but a print inside the func:

https://ibb.co/vmQQwYm

Comment: Check my last edit, see if it logs user object

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the problem is not that the function does not work, the issue is that it won't deploy: https://ibb.co/vmQQwYm

Comment: Dude, do you have internalFunctions.js inside functions folder

Comment: That was lazy of me. Deleted it (was there for testing) now working. Srry about that!